# Bundle can't install RMagick gem on Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rmagick

I've installed ImageMagick with ImageMagick installer script https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer. I am on OSX Lion 10.7, using RVM, Ruby 1.9.3p125.

The problem seems to be with MagickWand.h here is the complete log

```
/Users/pdjimeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
extconf.rb:128: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for /usr/bin/gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'MagickCore' found
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/pdjimeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
```

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/400179/gcc-on-os-x-lion-with-xcode-4-3-1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suggest that you use [brew](https://brew.sh/) to manage your binary dependencies. You can easily install imageMagick with [brew](https://brew.sh/), like this:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

This is what I have on my system:

```
imagemagick 6.7.1-1
http://www.imagemagick.org
Depends on: jpeg, libtiff, little-cms, jasper
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.1-1 (1389 files, 32M)
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
```

And I have the same setup as you have in terms of machine and ruby-version.

Comment: Imagemagick is already installed, I think that's not the problem.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is exactly with the installation. That some headers are not where they are expected to be, or they are missing all together. I guess simply uninstalling imagemagick and installing it with brew is easier than debugging this quite complex stack trace. But suite your self =)

Answer (score 46):

fix this setting the include path of your current imagemagick installation:

Install ImageMagick with brew

```
brew install imagemagick
```

find library

```
$ mdfind MagickWand.h
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/wand/MagickWand.h
```

Install rmagick gem

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/path gem install rmagick
```

example:

```
$ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Same here. Used the last example ending at ImageMagick/ directory.

Comment: The line `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.5-7/include/ImageMagick/ gem install rmagick` allowed me to install rmagick succesfully. This is the most accurate answer.

Comment: It may work either way in any case, but running `find /usr/local/Cellar -name MagickCore.pc` and setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable solved it for me.

Answer (score 27):

If you're getting Package `xxx` was not found.

Find the package and add it's dir path to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable in your `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile` file.

Example:

If you get the error:

```
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

Find where the file is:

```
$ mdfind magickcore.pc
/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
```

Add to your bash_login or bash_profile:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"`

remember to source the bash_login/profile file

Comment: The only thing that worked for me, tried all of the above. But only `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick` did the trick.

Comment: Using `sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick` I was able to get the rmagick install to complete. 

However, there were other issues and unlinking and reinstalling imagemagick was ultimately necessary. Ruby *is* more mature than Node.js et al yet switching between different versions of Ruby and Gems is still not straightforward.

Comment: This one worked for me. I'm on Mountain Lion with homebrew + rbenv.

Comment: C_INCLUDE_PATH didn't work, but this helped, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

At the time of writing this, imagemagick 7 is the default version installed via `brew install imagemagick`, but is incompatible with `rmagick`. Fix this by:

1. Remove currently installed version of imagemagick with homebrew

`brew uninstall imagemagick`

2. Install imagemagick 6:

`brew install imagemagick@6`

3. Run gem install with pkgconfig variable (may have to `sudo` depending on your config)

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 16):

Also found a solution using homebrew:

```
brew remove --force pkg-config
brew install pkg-config
```

and then

```
gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 8):

1) install by installer

http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/

2) try gem install rmagick

if checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
type

```
mdfind MagickWand.h
```

find some thing like

```
/Users/user/ImageMagick-6.8.3/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h
```

and type in terminal

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Users/user/ImageMagick-6.8.3/include/ImageMagick-6/ gem install rmagick
```

if, after that you have this error (because a had it) "Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path."

type

```
mdfind MagickCore.pc
```

find some thing like /opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

and finally in terminal type:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me on mac

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick

Answer (score 5):

Andrey Yasinishyn's solution worked for me:

```
mdfind MagickCore.pc
```

find some thing like /opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc

and finally in terminal type:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ImageMagick/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```

Answer (score 3):

When I came up against this issue, it was complaining it couldn't find MagickCore.pc, so I did this;

```
$ mdfind MagickCore.h
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick/magick/MagickCore.h
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/magick/MagickCore.h

$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/
$ gem install rmagick
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I tried everything, but what ended up being the solution was:

`brew uninstall --force imagemagick` # removes all versions

then

`brew install imagemagick@6`

finally

`gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth I had this problem with Ruby ree-1.8.7-2012-02. Here's how I fixed it:

I removed ImageMagick and re-installed it

```
brew remove imagemagick 
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
```

I then added these symbolic links in /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.9-7/lib/

```
ln -s libMagick++-6.Q16.5.dylib libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-6.Q16.2.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-6.Q16.2.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

I then removed the Ruby version and re-installed it

```
rvm remove ree-1.8.7-2012-02
rvm install ree-1.8.7-2012-02
```

Finally installed the Gem

```
gem install rmagick -v '2.12.2'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For El Capitan Users,

Both PKG_CONFIG_FILE and C_INCLUDE_PATH needs to be included. The command that worked for me is:

`sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-4/include/ImageMagick/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-4/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick`

Comment: "6.9.2-4" folder changes depending on installed imagemagic version. Otherwise works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add both the env variables to make it work.  Something like this

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/lib/pkgconfig/ gem install rmagick
```