# Error installing Rmagick on Mountain Lion

Tags: imagemagick, rvm, bundler, osx-mountain-lion, rmagick

I have seen other people with the same issue of [installing RMagick on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676844/issue-with-installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick-on-mountain-lion) However none of the suggested solutions have allowed me to successfully install rmagick.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent    libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Things I have done:

```
Installed XCode
Installed the command line tools
Installed XQuartz
Installed homebrew with imagemagick library
Installed most recent version of RVM
Symlinked GCC
Uninstalled and reinstalled both RVM and imagemagick
```

Any ideas why I still can't download rmagick?

Answer (score 215, accepted):

It appears it's a problem reported on the Homebrew github repo (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625) blaming rmagick itself not supporting newer versions of imagemagick. On that same issue (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16625#issuecomment-11519383), you can find this link: https://coderwall.com/p/wnomjg  which actually worked for me. This is what he does:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib
ln -s libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib   libMagick++.dylib
ln -s libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib libMagickCore.dylib
ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib
```

Comment: With the release of rmagick 2.13.2, this workaround should no longer be required.  See answer below for details.

Comment: I don't have this file: libMagick++-Q16.7.dylib

Comment: Anyway worked with other two files, and a big command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645011/1197775, actually more than that command `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'`

Comment: This also works for MacPorts with ImageMagick 6.8.5-5, the library files are located in /opt/local/lib and have slightly different names.

Comment: It is works without `ln -s libMagickWand-Q16.7.dylib libMagickWand.dylib` for me.

Answer (score 31):

The latest version of rmagick (2.13.2) now supports imagemagick 6.8

- https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/pull/63
- http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/master/ChangeLog
- http://singlebrook.com/blog/rmagick-resurrected

Comment: Worked on Mountain Lion for me.

Comment: I had to do linking as suggested by Lonecat in order to install 2.13.2. 2.13.1 never worked though.

Answer (score 8):

What we did was the following:

```
cd /usr/local
git checkout 834ce4a Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
brew install imagemagick
```

This will install Imagemagick 6.7.7-6

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but I have been through a bunch of these responses and still wasn't able to get it to work. I found a random link in another language which actually solved the problem for me (http://sugiarto.webmuapp.com/Package_MagickCore_was_not_found_in_the_pkg_config_search_path). It looks like it was looking for PKG_CONFIG_PATH which was not set up.

What worked for me:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Then make sure it worked:

```
find /usr -name 'MagickCore.pc'
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
```

Then try installing rmagick again:

```
gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
```

Success! Hope this helps anyone else still running into this issue.

Comment: The link in this post is dead, but for anyone else getting the same error I did, this works (thanks!). `"No package 'MagickCore' found
Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing MagickCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable"`

Answer (score 2):

From other answers:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/lib/pkgconfig C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10645011/1197775 to know how to get these dirs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me on macOS Sierra.

```
brew uninstall pkg-config
brew install pkg-config
brew unlink pkg-config
brew link pkg-config
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old issue but it did happen to me recently. I am posting this for those that have tried all other answers and weren't able to resolve so far. Bumping the `rmagick` gem to version `2.13.4` has worked with Ruby `1.9.3` on MacOS.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

check my answer to openssl problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/13958931/497756 - just make sure that imagemagick was compiled including `*.pc` files - which is the default for most software but not all of it.

Comment: I don't know how that answers the problem with installing rmagick. I'm having that problem too on a freshly formatted laptop but I can't find any kind solution on your post.

Comment: yu would have to find file `*magic*.pc` and provide path to it's fdirectory when installing gem: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/imagemagic/lib/pkgconfig gem install rmagick`