# How to tell which openssl lib is actually being used by an RVM-installed ruby

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm

I discovered that I can successfully install ruby with any of the following commands:

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p327
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p327 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p327 --with-openssl-dir=/afdlkjasd_not_a_dir
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p327 --with-openssl-dirffadsf=/afdlkjasd_not_a_dir
```

Regardless of which of the above commands I used, I can then type:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3-p327
Using /home/clay/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
$ which ruby
/home/clay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
$ ruby -e "puts require('openssl')"
true
```

I appear to have ssl support regardless of what I do. I guess rvm or the ruby build process don't mind invalid options or values. I have no idea if the `--with-openssl-dir` option was respected even when I type it (apparently) correctly.

Is rvm linking my ruby with the openssl lib that I intended (the one in /usr/local)? **How do I tell which openssl lib a ruby was compiled/linked with?**

I'm using Linux Mint 13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby has quite complicated mechanisms for detecting libraries, every extension has it's own code for that. Fortunately most of the extensions support `pkg-config` so it's possible to force location of `*.pc` files:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/openssl/lib/pkgconfig rvm reinstall 1.9.3
rvm use 1.9.3
```

then after compilation you can verify on OSX:

```
find $MY_RUBY_HOME -name openssl.bundle | xargs otool -L
```

or on linux:

```
find $MY_RUBY_HOME -name openssl.so | xargs ldd
```

as for the `--with-openssl-dir=...` it is not fully supported by ruby, it should be `--with-opt-dir=...` + `--with-openssl`, opt-dir supports multiple paths separated with `:` starting from ruby 1.9.3-p327

Comment: Thank you so much, this gets me much further, although I am still confused. The output after running those two commands on my linux box shows it is linking to ~/.rvm/usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 whereas I had set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig. (Or is that expected?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the ruby executable's relationship to openssl.so?

Comment: is there `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libssl.pc` ? also you might need to specify additional `--with-opt-dir=/usr` hopefully ruby can detect it properly - although there might be problems of this because of how 64 bit platforms are handled.

Comment: as for the relationship - `openssl.so` is part of an extension and when you do `require 'openssl'` it will be automatically loaded.

Comment: I am definitely still missing some pieces in my understanding of what's going on, but I suppose I should channel my confusion into some additional questions on SO rather than ask you to explain the entire ruby build process to me here :-)

Comment: if you need more help talk to me(`mpapis`) here: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm

Comment: The `libssl.pc` file exists. I reinstalled with `--with-opt-dir=/usr` but it still says it's linking to the same ssl lib as before

Comment: you could `rm -rf $rvm_path/usr` - rvm would reinstall `libyaml` but use the system openssl (if it's possible)

Comment: Thanks mpapis, that works and is valuable to know. Deserves more upvotes than I can give. So would this mean it's not currently possible to have one rvm-installed ruby that uses the system openssl and another that uses the openssl in ~/.rvm/usr?

Comment: it might be not possible with current code in RVM1 and Ruby, RVM2 should make it a lot simpler / possible

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::VERSION"
```

Comment: Knowing the version helps partly (it says 1.1.0), so thank you and +1, but I can't accept the answer because it's still not enough to help me figure out which library it is linking against. I have many different files on my system whose names begin with openssl.so or libssl.so and I don't know which one is being linked. None of them have "1.1.0" in the file name.

Comment: (Or is it even using a shared library? Maybe it's compiled statically, I don't know.)