# Ruby and "You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile"

Tags: ruby, macos, openssl, rvm

Using rvm I upgraded my ruby to 1.9.3-p392, also added 2.0.0, anytime I try to use this version when I run my bundle command I get this error.

```
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are
available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

I have followed several different instructions on how to fix this. I have tried removing the version and installing it with the rvm options

```
--with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

I have installed OpenSSL with rvm, and macports. Both have not helped the problem. I even changed the file location of the ssl cert using this:

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/Users/DarkLord/.rvm/usr/ssl/cert.pem
```

No matter what I do I continue to get the error. 
Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: I had this same issue on Ubuntu; this seemed to resolve the problem: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4357#issuecomment-381561492

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The new way to do it, according to a comment by @Purplejacket above, is the following:

```sh
rvm autolibs homebrew
rvm install 2.1.1
rvm use 2.1.1
```

It's much easier.

Comment: thanks for the update this. Glad there is an easier way to fix this.

Answer (score 85):

This works for me:

`rvm get stable`

`brew install libyaml`

`rvm pkg install openssl`

`rvm install ruby-2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

`rvm use ruby-2.0.0`

All credits go to https://coderwall.com/p/tptocq

Comment: `rvm pkg install openssl` incurred a deprecation from rvm version 1.24.7.  If you type `rvm autolibs` it will show a help screen with some alternatives.  Personally I used the option #4 which was `rvm autolibs homebrew` then `rvm uninstall 2.0.0-p353` then `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`.  This didn't quite work, but it generated a .log file with some instructions to do brew doctor and unlink a few libs.  Then re-running that last rvm install command worked.

Answer (score 58):

This helps me install 1.9.3-head on Mac:

```
rvm get latest    
brew install openssl    
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-head --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

Comment: Also still works for me, on Mac OS 10.13.6 trying to reinstall ruby 2.2.0

Comment: This worked for me with Ruby 2.3.3 and macOS 10.14.3.

Comment: this should be the proper answer because of setting dynamic openssl-dir argument

Comment: Openssl v1.1 is what seems to work

Comment: I had a problem with `gem install rails` where it was failing to build PUMA native extensions related to openssl. In the end I did `rvm autolibs`, `rvm reinstall 3.1.2 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl``

Answer (score 14):

In my case after:

```
 1. brew install openssl
 2. rvm install ruby-2.6.0
```

`bundle install` failed with this error. The problem was that openssl was globally set so I had to install the new ruby version by setting the openssl directory explicitly.

So what I had to do was:

```
 1. rvm reinstall ruby-2.6.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
 2. rvm reload
```

*Assuming that `usr/local/opt/openssl` is where it is installed.*

After that `bundle install` ran successfully.

**Warning** when I tried this command with this path `/usr/local` like some answers suggested, it didn't work.

Comment: Also if you only run `rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.9` without the `--with-openssl-dir=` section then that won't work!

Comment: And if you do not know where is your openssl path you can get it by running `brew --prefix openssl`.

Comment: Combining the answers, I recommend ```rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.7 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` ``` as the final solution.

Answer (score 9):

To get this working again I had to install homebrew and move my mac ports out of the way. Then do the following after removing 1.9.3-p392 and 2.0.0-p0:

```
rvm get head --autolibs=3
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-opt-dir=/usr/bin
rvm install 2.0.0
```

There was something not working with my mac ports and openssl and make and configure. This was the only way I was able to get rvm to install ruby again with out getting openssl issues or make/configure issues.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Tried all kind of suggestions but only this worked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem glad I was able to help you out.

Answer (score 7):

In my case:

**Problem:** After installing ruby-2.3.1, I ran the command `bundle install` and then the error occurred.

**Solution:**

- I first installed **OpenSSL** on my machine. `$ brew install openssl`
- And then, reinstalled the ruby version I require (2.3.1) with the openssl.

  `$ rvm reinstall 2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

And this solved my problem!

Answer (score 5):

According to the following question:
[How to tell which openssl lib is actually being used by an RVM-installed ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956134/how-to-tell-which-openssl-lib-is-actually-being-used-by-an-rvm-installed-ruby/13958931)

It seems that the options `--with-openssl-dir=...` is no longer valid as of Ruby 1.9.3. I tried

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local --with-openssl
```

and it worked.

Comment: I just tried to run that and I got the following error: 'Error running 'make -j4''

Answer (score 4):

Fix which worked for me

```
rvm install 3.0.3 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1
```

PS. Find the correct openssl location in your machine and install ruby pointing to that path like above, mentioning the brew installed openssl@3 path doesnot work.

Comment: This didn't quite work, I had to change the path to `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1`. The `etc` folder doesn't have `lib` or `include`.

Comment: Tried this: rvm install ruby-3.1.4 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr at first but didn't wrok. So then trued this and it worked. I guess I was pointing to a wrong openssl location.

Answer (score 3):

macOS Catalina

```
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0
rvm reinstall 2.3.8 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Specific case for ruby version **3.0.3** or above

By default for brew and system and autolibs OpenSSL version is 3. Ruby 3.0.3  does not work with OpenSSL version 3 and ruby build silently ignores OpenSSL.

To build ruby properly use build options with OpenSSL 1 like this:

```bash
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig rvm reinstall 3.0.3 --with-openssl --with-openssl-lib=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib --with-openssl-include=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
```

Where path variables may be another - check your system.

Thanks to article [Ruby 3.0.3 with OpenSSL using MacPorts and RVM](https://mentalized.net/journal/2021/11/29/ruby-3-0-3-rvm-and-openssl-1-1/)

Comment: Thanks for this.  Surprisingly, problem still happens on 3.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me.

First ensure `openssl` is installed by running `brew install openssl`, then reinstall the ruby version using rvm, but this time around, you have to pass the `with-opt-dir` flag pointing to the location where openssl was installed on your machine (use command `which openssl` to find this location).

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p392 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

On macOS 10.14, Ruby 2.5.3, and OpenSSL 1.0.2n this worked for me:

```
./configure --with-openssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl
```

but I was only trying what the error messages were telling me:

```
*** Following extensions are not compiled:
openssl:
    Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
    /Users/brian/Desktop/Ruby/ruby-2.5.3/ext/openssl/extconf.rb:97: OpenSSL library could not be found. You might want to use --with-openssl-dir=<dir> option to specify the prefix where OpenSSL is installed.
    Check ext/openssl/mkmf.log for more details.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.
make[1]: *** [note] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when working on a **Ruby 2.2.3** application.

I had previously uninstalled the **MySQL database server** on my machine, since I did not need it. However, I still needed the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem since my application was connecting to another application's MySQL database to pull data.

However, when I try to run the `bundle` command I get the error:

> Could not load OpenSSL.
> You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are
> available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was caused by removing the `libssl-dev` library when I was uninstalling the **MySQL database server** on my machine and its libraries.

First I ran the command below to reinstall `ruby` since I installed it using `rvm`:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.3
```

This raised an error:

> Making gemset ruby-2.2.3 pristine............................................./-
> .'command gem pristine --extensions mysql2 --version 0.5.3' failed, you need to fix these gems manually.
> .
> Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.2.3 gemset_pristine',
> please read /home/promisepreston/.rvm/log/1630094455_ruby-2.2.3/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.2.3.log

Next, I tried to install the mysql2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2
```

Then I ran into this error:

> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> mysql client is missing. You may need to 'sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev', 'sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'sudo yum install mysql-devel', and try again.

Finally, I installed the mysql client library using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

**Note**: This also installs the `libssl-dev` library alongside.

And everything worked fine.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

That's what helped me:

```
rvm reinstall 2.5

brew tap raggi/ale
brew install openssl-osx-ca
brew services start openssl-osx-ca
```

Found this solution here: https://github.com/raggi/openssl-osx-ca#readme

Answer (score 0):

I specified a more recent Ruby version in my Gemfile, then ran bundle install. All good now.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on Ubuntu 22.04 by doing:

`rvm pkg install openssl`

...and adding `--with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr` to the rvm install command.

This doesn't seem particularly OS-specific and might work on Mac OS as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use rvm, and I don't want to. I had to install asdf in order to resolve what I used to be able to do with just homebrew & ruby.

[Following this guide](https://ankane.org/ruby-openssl-1-1) is the only thing that worked for me after following dozens of suggestions. I had to [install asdf](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/5.html) and update my .zshrc to include the following at the end of the doc:

`eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"`

I'm on an Intel Mac running Monterey 12.2.1.