# What's the best way to run a RoR project on my localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have a friend's website code, which is in Ruby on Rails.

I have tried to install RoR on my Mac using instructions at [gorails.com](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave)

**OS** : Mac Mojave
**ruby -v** : ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin18]
**rails -v** :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

**What I tried** : I installed ruby, and then rails, using gorails tutorial, and kept getting errors stating version number mismatch.
Keep in mind that creating a new app, worked, but trying to run this existing code is a problem.
So then I uninstalled everything and updated the version using `rvm`, and since then I am getting this error.

When I `cd` into the webapp folder and run `bundle install`, I get errors, such as:

```
zsh: /Users/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@hs/bin/bundle: bad interpreter: /Users/abc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby: no such file or directory
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
```

This project uses a PostgreSQL database, which I have setup already.
If required, I can share the gemfile of this project too.

What is the best way to get this project working?
Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: check these links, they might help: [first](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4357), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212104/ruby-and-you-must-recompile-ruby-with-openssl-support-or-change-the-sources-in), One more thing, you have to clear your question, add things like your OS, Rails and Ruby version you are working on and what you have tried.

Comment: Why do you have RVM and rbenv at the same time?

Comment: Thanks @AmrAdel, I added more details.

Comment: @mechnicov : I am a newbie in RoR, and this could be because of my ignorance, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run RVM and RBENV on the same machine.  Pick one and remove the other.  You're probably best to uninstall both and then pick one, start over.

[Uninstall RBENV instructions here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/148)  or in your case probably `brew uninstall rbenv`

Uninstall RVM see [How can I remove RVM (Ruby Version Manager) from my system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

Close all terminals and then start a new one.

Install RVM see https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Then go to your project, make sure you have the correct ruby version needed by your project.  If not, you will need to install with `rvm install 2.5.1` for example.

Then run

```
rvm use 2.5.1 #or some other version
```

Then you should be able to run `bundle install`

The rest of the instructions in your link should be ok.

Comment: Thank you so much. This path led me to the position where openssl support was required, so I researched and got that fixed, then I had to fix issues related to rmagick, ports etc. I kept reading through the error message and now I am at a point where my `bundle install` succeeds. Which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!