# Rails 3.2 + Fedora15 : Not able to install rmagik

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the last few days I've been trying to install rmmagik gem in my fedora 15 machine but with no luck. Here's what I have done so far after going through countless forums and threads.

Yum install imagemagick
Yum install imagemagick-devel
gem install rmagik

at this point i got error like

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagickCore... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick... no
checking for InitializeMagick() in -lMagick++... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-MagickCorelib
    --without-MagickCorelib
    --with-Magicklib
    --without-Magicklib
    --with-Magick++lib
    --without-Magick++lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

After this I tried installing ImageMagik from source.
but the same error appears when installing rmagik. 
Please help.

Oh BTW i have been trying to set up RubyMine IDE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it running after i correctly set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

and then installed ImageMagick and Imagemagick-devel packages using "yum".
Now rubyMine is up and running :-D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a couple of days ago albeit on OSX, here is the [post and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942443/error-installing-rmagick-on-mountain-lion)

Comment: ok. I've gone through that thread u mentioned . But no luck . From what i've read it seems like rmagick is not getting the library files for MagickCore ,Magick , Magick++. I tried setting the environment veriable PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig . this path contrains the above mentioned libraries . this also failed.