# How to undo a C_INCLUDE_PATH command?

Tags: command-line, path, osx-mavericks

I was attempting to resolve an issue I was having with the rmagick gem using the 2nd answer on this: [Bundle can't install RMagick gem on Mac OSX 10.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063051/bundle-cant-install-rmagick-gem-on-mac-osx-10-7)

However, when I typed in the command C_INCLUDE_PATH= I accidentally started it with two slashes like so: C_INCLUDE_PATH=//usr...

I'd like to remove/undo this command but I'm not sure how. Help?

Info: on OSX 10.9 Mavericks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the value, just retype the same command with a single '/' 
`C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr...` [ENTER]

To undo, just type 
`C_INCLUDE_PATH=` [ENTER]

Comment: Is there some way I can view the current value of the path to verify this worked?